# npm build library after installation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am building a private npm package with react and webpack, so it needs to be built before it can be used.
I also need to uninstall the devdependencies after the package has been installed because it uses react as a peer dependency and I can not use mutliple instances of react.

My first approach was to add a prepare script:

```
"prepare": "npm run build && npm prune --production"
```

The problem is that, when I install dependencies inside this package, the prepare script is also called and removes all of the devdependencies.

How can I run a script only when the package itself is installed, but not when install is run inside the package?

Comment: You want to set those as peer dependencies in your private npm package https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies

Comment: Yes they already are peerDeps but for development I also need them as dev dependencies which as I described in the question will be removed when running "npm install"

Comment: Why is your build command installing your dev dependencies if you dont want them to be installed?